# Casting string to bigint in hive returns incomplete data

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-hive, hivecontext, spark-hive

How do I get the full value in hive? i.e. `cast('0024' as bigint)` will give only `24` but I need the complete `0024` as my output.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `24` is the right answer.  If you need zeros before the number, then use a string.

Comment: But I need 0024 because at target end I need to perform few computations and from source side that particular record value is coming as 00004546... Hence need full value

Comment: As a bigint, the full value is "24".  If you need zeroes prepended to the value, then use a string.

Comment: You have contradicting statements in your question  .. If you are trying to convert it into an integer , it inherently means that you are gonna work with the value of the integer . If you insist that you need to do some thing at the other end , why not use a string and do operations on it

Comment: Please provide more context for any further help